# How to change pelican-bootstrap3 background-color's code background color

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, pelican

My pelican blogs uses theme pelican-bootstrap3, and the color of code is always grey, link below,[image]

I just want it to be [image]
How to change its background-color to other colors.

Answer (score 1):

There are [various](http://pygments.org/demo/5862471/) syntax highlighting styles available for Pygments. The one you are using is the default style. If you have not installed Pygments already, install it by executing:

```
pip install Pygments
```

and put:

```
PYGMENTS_STYLE = 'your_style_here'
```

in your ***"pelicanconf.py"*** and replacing ***"your_style_here"*** with your preferred style.